# jqGrid page navigation not working on Firefox or Chrome

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, jqgrid

[page navigation](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/9468/capturefow.png)

The issue is that on FF and Chrome when I hover the mouse over the >> or >| arrows it does not highlight, and therefore not working. Although in Firefox there is a very VERY slim hover area at the top but you must be a brain surgeon to have that steady of a hand to hit it.

I have jqGrid  3.5.1 and the latest version is jqGrid 4.1.2 but the update is a no go :(.

Anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use ASP.NET MVC or you can other CSS problem you should try to include the following CSS style

```
input.ui-pg-input { width: auto; }
```

Additionally the usage of

```
table { border-style:none; border-collapse:separate; }
table td { border-style:none; }
```

or

```
div.ui-jqgrid-view table.ui-jqgrid-btable
{
    border-style: none;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
div.ui-jqgrid-view table.ui-jqgrid-btable td
{
    border-left-style: none;
}
div.ui-jqgrid-view table.ui-jqgrid-htable {
    border-style:none;
    border-collapse:separate;
}
div.ui-jqgrid-view table.ui-jqgrid-btable th {
    border-left-style:none
}
```

can be important to solve problems with horizontal scroll bars (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/fixing-problems-with-the-calculation-of-the-grid-width-for-asp-net-mvc-projects/#p22685) for more details)

If it will not help you should include in the text of your question the full code example (including all CSS which you use) which can be used to reproduce your problem.