# JqGrid pagination dropdown is not working on Firefox

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, jqgrid, paging, dropdown

In an MVC web application I am using JqGrid control. It's working on almost all the browsers.

However on Mozilla Firefox the Paging dropdown is not clickable. I'm not able to click on the Paging dropdown to select no. of record to show.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9duXr.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362048/jqgrid-page-navigation-not-working-on-firefox-or-chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jqGrid page navigation not working on Firefox or Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362048/jqgrid-page-navigation-not-working-on-firefox-or-chrome)